# How to avoid repeated expression in formula in Excel

Tags: excel, performance

I'm sure someone will ask "Who cares?" but having been (badly?) influenced by a former colleague early in my career ("Never ever repeat the same calculation, just store the result and reuse it!") I'm updating an Excel spreadsheet which currently displays the weekday for days in the current year, using

```
=IF(AU2=0,DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2)),"")
```

where column A, rows 2-367 ("n" in the above formula), contain dates from 2016-01-01 to 2016-12-31, displayed as "1 January" to "31 December"

Column AW contains the above formula to display the weekdays, in (obviously) the current year where the value in column AU is zero.

To make the results a bit more dynamic, i.e. to display the weekday of the next year (potentially conditionally formatted in another colour)  if year(today()) + the month and day of column A are before today, I can change the formula in column AW to

```
=IF(AU2=0,IF(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2))<TODAY(),DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+1,MONTH(A2),DAY(A2)),DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2))),"")
```

(and to the same to the formulas in columns AX/AY/AZ, which display the weekdays if

```
AX: AU <> 0 & AU <= 250
AY: AU <> 0 & 250 < AU <= 500
AZ: UU <> 0 & 500 < AU <= 1000
```

but that results in the same long-winded calculation of the date being repeated 1,464 times, and this particular sheet is already quite slow, as it contains data for 39 years.

So, is there an (easy) way to simplify this kind of processing, like adding a (hidden) column containing the calculated date, or a thisyear/nextyear indicator to speed things up? Or do I just accept the "Who cares!" attitude?

Comment: Not sure if it's what you're looking for, but if you use EDATE you can easily calculate the next year: `=EDATE([your data for the current year date],12)`. This adds 12 months (= 1 year) to the current year.

Answer (score 0):

In the worksheet, select the formula you want to make it reusable, and then click the New Autotext button. 3. In the New AutoText dialog box, type a name for this auto text entry in Name box, select Formulas in Group drop-down list, and then click the Add button.

see [https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2634-excel-reuse-formula.html#:~:text=In%20the%20worksheet%2C%20select%20the,then%20click%20the%20Add%20button](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2634-excel-reuse-formula.html#:%7E:text=In%20the%20worksheet%2C%20select%20the,then%20click%20the%20Add%20button). for more information

Comment: this uses a plugin from KUTools, rather than any built-in Excel functionality.